# PHFetchOptions Duration not working properly

Tags: objective-c, swift, nspredicate, phasset, phfetchoptions

I'm trying to fetch all the **Videos** which their duration is higher than 1.5 sec.

**What i have tried**

```
        let videoOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        let dur : Double = 1.5
        videoOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        videoOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d AND duration > %d", PHAssetMediaType.Video.rawValue,dur)
        VideoCollectionFetchResult =  PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(videoOptions)
```

The docs says :

[image]

**Any suggestions? Thanks!**

Comment: what is the problem actually? Don't you get results or you get wrong results?

Comment: @KaterynaGridina  wrong results. Like it's ignoring the duration part(only)

Comment: can be related to the format - duration is actually Double format, and %d is for integer. Try to use %f, like: (format: "mediaType = %d AND duration > %f", PHAssetMediaType.Video.rawValue,dur)

Comment: @KaterynaGridina oh Ah. Good catch! Post an answer so i can accept it haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to the format - duration is actually Double format, and %d is for integer. Try to use %f, like:

```
(format: "mediaType = %d AND duration > %f", PHAssetMediaType.Video.rawValue,dur)
```

Answer (score 1):

Kateryna's answer is fine but it's not completed code. So instead of spending time parsing the answer together, here's working code:

```
let videoOptions = PHFetchOptions()
videoOptions.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true) ]
videoOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d AND duration > %f", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue, 1.5) // only video and 1.5 seconds or more

return videoOptions
```